# how to delete multiple empty fields

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to delete all fields that have empty values, but I'm not getting it, I tried that way but it wouldn't work.
`DELETE FROM ctuser WHERE (SELECT *FROM ctuser WHERE nome = '')`;

Comment: Do you want to delete the field or the whole row?

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` by `empty fields`? If so, try `DELETE FROM ctuser WHERE nome IS NULL`

Comment: `DELETE FROM ctuser`  will do it, but it will also delete the other rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:
`DELETE FROM ctuser WHERE nome = '' OR nome IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

If you do: `DELETE FROM ctuser WHERE (SELECT *FROM ctuser WHERE nome = '');`

Then mysql will first do: `SELECT *FROM ctuser WHERE nome = ''`

This might result in multiple records, or no records.

After that MySQL will do `DELETE FROM ctuser WHERE x`. With multiple records at the place of the `x`, and that is not a valid SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help